When is the product with both the symmetric and alternating parts of a character irreducible?
Let $G$ be a finite group, $\chi: G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an irreducible character. Then the following two maps are also characters: $$\chi_S : g \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\chi(g)^2 + \chi(g^2));$$ $$\chi_A : g \longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\chi(g)^2 - \chi(g^2)).$$
Sometimes there exists another irreducible character $\theta: G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (with degree $ >1 $) such that the product $ \theta \chi_S $ is irreducible or the product $ \theta \chi_A $ is irreducible. But it seems that there is some reason that $ \theta \chi_S $ and $ \theta \chi_A $ cannot both be irreducible for the same $ \theta $.
The only exception I have found is that if $ \chi $ is one of the 2d irreps of $ SL(2,5) $ and $ \theta $ is the other 2d irrep of $ SL(2,5) $, then $ \theta \chi_A= \theta $ and $ \theta \chi_S $ is the 6d irrep of $ SL(2,5) $.
It seems that for any finite group $ G $ other than $ SL(2,5) $ it is impossible for $ \theta \chi_S $ and $ \theta \chi_A $ to be simultaneously irreducible. For example I have used GAP to check that $ SL(2,5) $ is the only perfect group of size $ <200,000 $ with this property. Is there some conceptual explanation for this fact? Or it just totally random chance?

Suppose $\chi$ is the character of a representation $V$, so $\chi_S$ is the character of the second symmetric power $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V$ and $\chi_A$ is the character of the second exterior power $\bigwedge^2 V$. Say $\theta$ is the character of a representation $W$. Then $\theta \chi_S$ is the character of $W \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^2 V$ and $\theta \chi_A$ is the character of $W \otimes \bigwedge^2 V$, which decomposes $W \otimes V^{\otimes 2} = (W \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^2 V) \oplus (W \otimes \bigwedge^2 V)$. Both $\theta \chi_S$ and $\theta \chi_A$ are irreducible if and only if $W \otimes V^{\otimes 2}$ is a sum of two irreducibles (well, when $\dim V > 1$; if $\dim V = 1$, then $\chi_A=0=\theta\chi_A$ is not irreducible anyway).
That is, you're asking why $W \otimes V^{\otimes 2}$ is almost never a sum of exactly two irreducibles. I'd say it's fairly intuitive that this should be quite rare, since tensor products of irreducibles are "almost never" irreducible, except when one of the factors is $1$-dimensional. See this thread for further discussion, which explicitly mentions your $\mathrm{SL}(2, 5)$ example (through the exceptional isomorphism $\mathrm{SL}(2, 5) = 2.A_5$).
More precisely, $V^{\otimes 2}$ has at least two irreducibles (since $\dim V > 1$), and "generically" $V^{\otimes 2}$ will have $\geq 3$ irreducibles, in which case your property will fail. If $V^{\otimes 2}$ has exactly two irreducibles (rare), you'll need both of their tensor products with $W$ to be irreducible (double rare, if $\dim W > 1$). So when $\dim W > 1$, you're asking for three rare things to happen at once--this is the situation of your $\mathrm{SL}(2, 5)$ example. When $\dim W = 1$, you may as well use $\theta = 1$, and you're asking when $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V$ and $\bigwedge^2 V$ are both irreducible if $V$ is.
Overall it's not surprising to me that you've found very few examples, though I don't have a quantitative version of that statement.
